# Create column using multiple conditions and tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to create a column for a list of products based on some other tables in Power BI. `table1` is a full list of products I want to investigate,

`table1`:

```
id  product_name 
1   xl1
2   xl2
3   s11
4   m11
...
```

I want to create a column `city` based on another table, table2:

```
id  product_name   city
1   xl1            D
2   xl1            A 
3   xl1            A 
4   xl1            A 
5   xl1            A 
6   s11            B
7   s11            B
8   s11            B
9   m11            C
```

If `product_name` in `table1` is also found in `table2`, look for `city`, if there is only one value, fill the new column with the value, if there are two values, write 'both', if `product_name` cannot be found in `table2`, write 'no value'

Expected output:

```
id  product_name  new_col
1   xl1           both   (because city =D,A in table2)
2   xl2           no value
3   s11           B
4   m11           C
...
```

How should I approach a problem like this in Power BI? Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following `dax` measure to achieve your outcome, so when you know that the `product` appear in more than 1 unique city, it will return both and accept the solution if help :)

```
Column = 
var result1 = CALCULATE(FIRSTNONBLANK(Table2[city],1),
                FILTER(ALL(Table2),Table2[product_name] = EARLIER(Table1[product_name])))
var distint = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table2[city]),
                FILTER(ALL(Table2),Table2[product_name]=EARLIER(Table1[product_name])))
return
IF(distint>1,"both",IF(ISBLANK(result1),"no value",result1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Kin, thanks for your answer, could you please briefly explain it?

Comment: May I know what the `1` in `FIRSTNONBLANK(Table2[city],1)` means?

Comment: Sorry I miss out you message, i guess 1 mean the first return or value, let me confirm about it

Comment: I think I invoke `Firstnonblank` because I need to return the `text` using calculation, When the formula cannot found anything using `Firstnonblank`, it will return blank, `1, 2, 3` will not affect the result. You may refer to this link for other method to use https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/FIRSTNONBLANK-to-generate-a-column/td-p/594024

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the additional information. I will have a look :)

Comment: Welcome, but please take note the latest update in PowerBi introduced `GTP3`, which is going to replace `dax` in future, haha.